# python with flashdrives and linux commands

Tags: python, tkinter, usb-flash-drive, easygui

I have 2 questions.

So i am making a python program that will backup and restore a selected directory for me.

This is my first program and i am using easygui as my gui for this program.

what i want to know is how i can take a linux command that is executed and display the result of that in a msgbox , or would tkinter be better for this kind of thing?

and how would i go about showing what flash drives are plugged in with this as in showing a drop down menu of the flash drives plugged in that you can pick from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import commands
from easygui import *

output = commands.getstatusoutput("command")
msgbox(msg=output[1])
```

That's how you get the output of a command and show it in a message box.

Comment: is there anyway i can do two commands in one box?

because when i do 

    os.system('cd /media')

it dosent cd back to media

Comment: @Huntaz556 As far as I know you can't use `cd` in scripts and programs, you'll have to do whatever you want to do _from_ the directory you ran the script in. You can display two commands in one message box by making a string, adding both outputs into that string and display it in the message box.